# Render Facebook friends with 'registered' attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala, rabl

Basycally what I would like to do is to :

- Get the Facebook friends of a the current user
- Render this collection while differentiating user who are already registered with my app to other users by adding a 'registered' attribute set to `true` or `false` to each item of this collection

I've managed to retrieve the Facebook friends of the current user and serve it to my app like so

**UserController**

```
  def facebook_friends
    @friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
  end
```

**RABL**

```
object false
node :data do @friends
end
```

It returns something like:

```
{
  data: [{
    'id': '23456789'
    'name': 'Bobby Brown'
  }, {
    'id': '23456788'
    'name': 'Bobby Black'
  }]
}
```

but what I would like is something like this:

```
{
  data: [{
    'id': '23456789'
    'name': 'Bobby Brown',
    'registered': true
  }, {
    'id': '23456788'
    'name': 'Bobby Black',
    'registered': false
  }]
}
```

But I have no idea how to do the second part without wasting too much resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is simple Graph API query for that.

```
me/friends?fields=id,name,installed
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

It returns JSON. Users who installed app have `installed: true`

```
@graph.get_connections('me','friends',:fields=>"id,name,installed")
```

Comment: Not exactly how I thought I'd do it, but I guess that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean registered with your app

You can use FQL instead to built the response you need as the `user` table has a registered field called `is_app_user`

`SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Which should return something like

```
{
  data: [{
    'id': '23456789'
    'name': 'Bobby Brown',
    'is_app_user': true
  }, {
    'id': '23456788'
    'name': 'Bobby Black',
    'is_app_user': false
  }]
}
```

If you mean users who are Facebook verified, I think it only works on the authenticated user.

The field is `verified`

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend